# Finding a comma in a string then separating the x and y values that correspond with it

Tags: c++, string, file

I'm currently working on a parser for a small script system I'm building for my game engine. Right now I'm trying to break a line's string into parts so I can figure out the information. For example, let's say I have this line saved into a script called gui.ss:

```
150,200
```

These two integers are seperated by a comma with no spaces in between them at all. What I basically want to do is figure out where the numbers are in order to save 150 to an x value coordinate integer, then a y value coordinate integer. Any help is great, thanks!

Comment: "Right now I'm trying to break a line's string into parts so I can figure out the information." Isn't that the job of a lexer rather than a parser? If you break down the input into tokens first then it ought to be really easy to recognize a number token followed by a comma token followed by another number token. The tokens should readily provide the values you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stringstream:

```
std::string str;
size_t commaPosition = str.find(',');
str.replace( commaPosition, 1, " " );

stringstream ss;
ss << str;
int x, y;
ss >> x >> y;
```

Comment: All answers were great, but I liked that there was no c-style functions in this one. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

std::string raw = "150,200";
size_t i = raw.find(',');
int x = atoi(raw.substr(0, i).c_str());
int y = atoi(raw.substr(i + 1).c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string text = "150,200";
int x = strtol(text.c_str(), NULL, 10);
std::size_t pos = text.find(',');
int y = strtol(text.c_str() + pos + 1, NULL, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently working on a parser for a small script system I'm building for my game engine. 
>   Right now I'm trying to break a line's string into parts so I can figure out the 
>   information.

Unless you really want it, do not reinvent the wheel. At least not from scratch. If you're starting your project consider using [existing parser tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

You may even use something embedded like [LUA](http://www.lua.org/) or [TCL](http://www.tcl.tk/) or [Python](http://www.python.org/). It will gave your user the power of the langage and the existing libs.